# eigenspaces of Unimodular contraction in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

The question asks

If $T$ is a contraction on a Hilbert space $H$ and $\lambda$ be unimodular eigenvalue of $T$. Then to show that $\bar{\lambda}$ is unimodular eigenvalue of $T^*$ and compare eigenspaces correnponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ in $T$ and corresponding to $\bar\lambda$ in $T^*$.

Now for the 1 st part I was doing

$<T^*x,y>=<x,Ty>=<x,\lambda y>
=<\bar\lambda x,y>$ which implies
$<T^*x-\bar\lambda x,y>=0$ but we can conclude if this is true for all $y$. So I am not sure whether we can conclude that here . But where to use contraction and unimodular eigenvalue? And how to compare the eigenspaces?

Any insight would be very very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If $Tx=\lambda x$ and $\|x\|=1,$ $|\lambda|=1,$ then $$1=\langle Tx,Tx\rangle ={\lambda}\langle x,Tx\rangle = \lambda\langle T^*x,x\rangle =\langle T^*x,\bar{\lambda}x\rangle $$
Therefore $T^*x=\bar{\lambda}x.$
Consequently $\ker(T-\lambda I)\subseteq\ker(T^*-\bar{\lambda} I).$ Exchanging the roles of $T$ and $T^*$ we get the opposite inclusion, hence $\ker(T-\lambda I)= \ker(T^*-\bar{\lambda} I).$

We have used a simple fact that for two vectors $u,v$ such that $\|u\|\le 1$ and $\|v\|\le 1$ the condition $\langle u,v\rangle =1$ implies $u=v.$ Moreover we based on the property that $T^*$ is a contraction, as $\|T^*\|=\|T\|.$

Comment: So the corresponding eigenspaces would be equal?

Comment: Yes. The  kernels are the eigenspaces